# Why is Ansible ignoring my inventory file?

Tags: ansible

I've just installed Ansible on Ubuntu 19.04.
The environment variable, `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` is empty.
I have a local `ansible.cfg` file pointing to a local inventory file (called hosts).
The local inventory file (hosts) identifies two routers (R1 and R2).
These devices, R1 and R2, are in my /etc/hosts file, and I can SSH to them.
`ansible --version` shows my config file is `/home/paddy/ansible.cfg`.
`ansible --list-hosts all` says there's no hosts file.

When I remove the local `ansible.cfg` file, and put the local inventory file (hosts) into `/etc/ansible`, and then run, I get:

```
$ansible --list-hosts all
    hosts (2):
      R1
      R2
```

This is as expected.
Unfortunately, when I use the local `ansible.cfg` file, it doesn't see the inventory file (`/home/paddy/hosts`)

1. Environment Variable is not set:

```
$echo $ANSIBLE_CONFIG

    <nothing>
```

2. Local `ansible.cfg` file (in `/home/paddy`) is as follows:

```
    [defaults]
    hostfile = /home/paddy/hosts
    host_key_checking = False
    timeout = 5
```

3. Local inventory file (in `/home/paddy` called `hosts`):

```
    [routers]
    R1
    R2
```

4. Files in `/home/paddy`:

```
$ls -l
    total 52
    -rw-r--r-- 1 paddy paddy   79 Aug 19 16:54 ansible.cfg
    -rw-r--r-- 1 paddy paddy   17 Aug 19 16:55 hosts
    <redacted directories>
```

5. The output of `ansible --version`

```
$ansible --version
    ansible 2.8.4
      config file = /home/paddy/ansible.cfg
      configured module search path = [u'/home/paddy/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
      ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
      executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
      python version = 2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

6. The output of `ansible --list-hosts all.`

```
$ansible --list-hosts all
    [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. 
    Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'.

    hosts (0):
```

I expected to see:

```
$ansible --list-hosts all

    hosts (2):
       R1
       R2
```

What I get is:

```
$ansible --list-hosts all

    [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. 
    Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'.

    hosts (0):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Ini Key* is [*inventory*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-host-list)

Wrong

```
[defaults]
hostfile = /home/paddy/hosts
```

Correct

```
[defaults]
inventory = /home/paddy/hosts
```

---

Note

It's possible to use environment variables in *ansible.cfg*. For example

```
[defaults]
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
library = $PWD/modules:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules
...
```